# LSTM : How do I get result of predict(x_test) as 2d

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

I am building my lstm model to predict bitcoin price. I am having a problem with predict(x_test). predict(x_test)'s result should be a 2d(dimension), `but it is kept in a 3d.`

`How do I get 2d as a result of 'predict(x_test)'?`

In my model

```
x_train : (405, 7, 1)
y_train : (405,)
x_test : (103, 7, 1)
y_test : (103, 1)
```

Here is my code.

```
#model create
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(7, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1))) # input_shape : (7,1)
model.add(LSTM(10, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(90, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy','mae'])

# Predict
prediction=model.predict(x_test)
prediction.shape
```

Here's the desired result:

- Result of 'predict(x_test)' is 2d as (103, 1)

I am trying to search google, but I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove return_sequences=True for the last LSTM layer.

So your model will be:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(7, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1))) # input_shape : (7,1)
model.add(LSTM(10))
model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(90, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
```